# What does 'PPT' stand for, in the context of a shop?

Tags: acronyms

"PPT" is the technical name for the price labels put in front of products in shops, often with a discounted price on them. What does PPT actually stand for?

Comment: Ask the shop...

Comment: What kind of shop? My first guess is "Price per Thousand", but obviously I'm more confident in that guess if it's a bulk store than if it's an auto dealer.

Comment: Well, I've never seen such labels, I think. There's no way we can answer this question without additional details.

Comment: We really need to know which country you saw these labels in, although @monoRed's suggestion of *price per thousand* is a good one.

Comment: It's apparently an established abbreviation for _pay per transaction_, but I'm not convinced that really makes sense in this context.

Comment: Add a photo, if possible. This is a great example of something that is almost impossible to search for, as a flood of unrelated ".ppt" (PowerPoint) files and file mentions appear in any search and are very hard to filter out.

Comment: Without a picture it's difficult to be sure, but googling suggests that either Printed or Plastic Price Tag is likely

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, and sorry about the lack of clarification. I've seen the signs in shops in England, and I'm going to accept Phil's answer of Promotional Price Tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Promotional price tag.**

> A system to detect and maintain retail store promotional price tags
>   (PPTs) includes a heuristic PPT description extractor module, a
>   heuristic rule deriver module, a store shelf image acquisition system,
>   a barcode locator and recognizer module, and a heuristic PPT
>   classifier module.

http://www.freepatentsonline.com/y2016/0260051.html